# Opportunity Closed Lost Stage shows all open stages even not in my SalesProcess

Tags: opportunity, record-type, sales-process, stagename

THIS IS THE ISSUE:

**Q: Why are these stages showing? I only want "Gain Commitment" and "Lost-Closed".**
[image]

- My Record in question's RecordType is set to "Lost-CLosed"

[image]

- "Lost-Closed" Recordtype uses a SalesProcess Called "Lost-Closed
  Process"
- "Lost-Closed Process" Salesprocess has only 2 stages "Gain
  Commitment" and "Lost-Closed".

[image]

I expect only the 2 stages (Gain C... and Lost-...) to show in the SalesProcess Widget, 1 open stage and 1 closed stage, with Lost-Closed set.
Simple, yet I get all the other rubbish stages.
Surely this has got to be a Salesforce bug; If it is I will escalate it. But for now checking if I am missing something.

please don't tell me to deactivate the extra stages, no, they are relevant for other processes on other recordtypes, just not on Lost-Closed.

As a side:
Bugs I have found this week: Recordtypes cannot be named the same as a SalesProcess (vice versa) otherwise they do not retrieve or deploy properly.

Answer (score 1):

The Sales process is just to configure the picklist values that should be available for specific record type.

The widget you are looking is called [Sales Path](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.path_overview.htm&type=5), refer [this trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/customize-a-sales-path-for-your-team/customize-opportunity-stages) for configuring the opportunity stages in a Sales Path.

Comment: Sales Paths are not turned on. This is the standard path for the recordtype, there is no different info required for each stage (in the main there isn't)
That said I can see a small amount of value in using sales paths.